# How can I skip a piece of code in recursion?

Tags: python

```
def bin_to_decimal(inp, degree=0, result=0):
    arr = []
    for i in inp:
        arr.append(i)
    if not arr:
        return result
    else:
        x = arr.pop(-1)
        result += int(x)**degree
        return bin_to_decimal(inp, degree+1, result)


bin_to_decimal('1001')
```

Is it possible to skip this part of the function, when I call recursion?

```
arr = []
for i in inp:
    arr.append(i)
```

Comment: why are you reimplementing `return int(inp,2)` ?  and why is there no ` += 2**degree * int(x)` in your code?

Comment: Your function does two things: It created `arr` by copying it from `inp`, and then does a recursive process. You should separate it into two functions - one that performs the copy, and the other that performs the recursive processing. It is best to keep recursive functions as small as possible, and as centered on the recursion as possible, to promote readability. It is also better to use non-recursive code if possible, and in your case, it is very possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
def bin_to_decimal(inp, degree=0, result=0, skip=False):
    if skip:
        arr = []
        for i in inp:
            arr.append(i)
    if not arr:
        return result
    else:
        x = arr.pop(-1)
        result += int(x)**degree
        # Flag True to skip
        return bin_to_decimal(inp, degree+1, result, True)
```

But you will now have an unreferenced variable `arr`

- along with a few more errors

I suggest you have a look at some other methods that you can use:

Built-in:

```
>>> int('1001',2)
9
```

Iteration:

```
def bin_to_decimal(inp):
    x = 0
    for i in inp:
        x = x*2 + int(i)
    return x
```

Comment: `Exception has occurred: UnboundLocalError
local variable 'arr' referenced before assignment` - your "recursive" does not work - so no - **you can not use** that.

Comment: I know, I stated that in the answer that it doesn't work. The question was asking how to skip a section, not how to solve the entire function. I have added other working examples below

Answer (score 2):

`if whatever: ...` is possible in recursion as well and can skip things inside your function - but there is no need:

You do not need to add an *implicit carry* (`result=0`) to your function signature if you do recursion the right way:

```
def bin_to_decimal(inp, degree=0):
    if len(inp) == 1:  # base case
        return  2**degree*int(inp[0])

    # "12345" => "1234" into remainder and "5" into x by decomposition
    *remainder, x = inp # decompose

    # calc the value of x and recurse with remainder and 1 degree higher
    return 2**degree*int(x)+bin_to_decimal(remainder, degree+1)
    
for n in range(17):
    b = bin(n)[2:]  # this function converts int to bin with a 0b prefix
    print(b, bin_to_decimal(b), sep=" ==> ")
```

Output:

```
0 ==> 0
1 ==> 1
10 ==> 2
11 ==> 3
100 ==> 4
101 ==> 5
110 ==> 6
111 ==> 7
1000 ==> 8
1001 ==> 9
1010 ==> 10
1011 ==> 11
1100 ==> 12
1101 ==> 13
1110 ==> 14
1111 ==> 15
10000 ==> 16
```

Recursion is not needed here, you can unroll it:

```
def bin_to_decimal(inp):
    num = 0
    degree = 0
    for digit in inp[::-1]: # reversed
        num += int(digit) * 2**degree
        degree += 1
    return num
```

or simpy use `num =  int("0100101", 2)` to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "closest to your code as possible" solution, you can use:

```
def bin_to_decimal(inp, degree=0, result=0):
    arr = list(inp) # this does what your loop does ... just shorter
    # list("abc") => ["a","b","c"]
    # list(["a","b","c"]) => ["a","b","c"] where it is not needed

    if not arr:
        return result
    else:
        x = arr.pop(-1)
        result += int(x)**degree

        # use arr here, not inp
        return bin_to_decimal(arr, degree+1, result)
```

but using a carry like you do is bad style regarding recursion.